# Numbering of appendices in the backmatter of a book

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

I'm using the standard book class. If I write

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{foo}
\section{Donald}

\backmatter
\chapter{bar}
\section{Mickey}

\end{document}
```

I expect to have chapter bar numbered as appendix A and section Mickey as A.1. Instead chapter bar is not numbered and section Mickey is 1.2, following section Donald. If I insert the appendix command to obtain

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{foo}
\section{Donald}

\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{bar}
\section{Mickey}

\end{document}
```

then chapter bar is unnumbered and section Mickey is numbered as .1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simply remove the `\backmatter` in your second version. The `\backmatter` should only be the bibliography and index (and similar things) at the end, which are not numbered.

Answer (score 9):

Try putting `\backmatter` after your appendices?