# Book class appendix

Tags: sectioning, appendices

I am using the `book` LaTeX class and I want to add appendices.
I do this in the following way:

```
\usepackage{appendix}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Some title}
%...
```

My problem with this is that the `\chapter` seems to be taken as `\chapter*`. Because instead of **Appendix A. Some title** (which is what I want) the appendix that is just titled **Some title**.

Any idea how I can get the "Appendix A" in front of it?
I though this would standard behaviour in the `book` class. Possibly some other package is messing things up. For instance, I use `titlesec`, `hyperref` and `cleveref`.

Edit: clarification, I am talking about both the title in the text AND the ToC. Neither shows "Appendix A".

Comment: Are you talking about the title in the ToC or in the text? Also please complete your example. It's not a _working_ example.

Comment: I mean both. I edited question to clarify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by the fact that I had put `\backmatter` before `\appendix`. Putting `\backmatter` after the appendices solves the problem entirely.

It also turned out this problem had already been solved here: [Numbering of appendices in the backmatter of a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1884/3800)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not quite sure if I correctly understood your request. But try the following to get "Appendix A" in front of your entries in the ToC.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Some title}
Some text
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

ToC:

[image]

Title in text:

[image]

Comment: With this setup, you get a line in the ToC labelled "Appendices" followed by "Appendix A  Some Title". It may be better to replace the `\begin{appendices}` and `\end{appendices}` commands with a single `\appendix` instruction (while leaving the `\appendixpage`, `\noappendicestocpagenum`, and `\addappheadtotoc` instructions in place. This way, the entries for the individual appendix sections in the ToC will look like "A  Some Text". A second advantage of using `\appendix` is that `cleveref`'s `\cref` command will replace the prefix "section" with "appendix", which is probably what the OP wants.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I know, that you get "Appendix A Some title". The image above shows the ToC. I understand the OP's request in a way that he wants to change the title formatting in the ToC.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood the OP's request -- I thought he wanted "Appendix A" to show up at the start of the section. Upon re-reading the OP's question, I'd say your interpretation seems closer to the mark.

Comment: @Mico: you were both right. My problem is that "Appendix A" is shown neither in the text nor in the ToC

Comment: @Matthias But if you compile my code, there is "Appendix A" in the ToC and in the title in text.

Comment: @Thorsten: I in corporated your code in my document, but I get a different result. In the ToC I get: "Appendices\\Appendix Some title". But in the text the section is just titled with "Some title". I guess some pother package is inferring.

Comment: @Matthias But if you compile only my code you get the same result as I posted above? If this is the case it would be the best if you'd edit your question and complete the MWE.

Comment: @Thorsten: Sorry, I should have done that first. Your code works if I compile it separately. Thanks. I will try to construct an MWE that exposes my problem.

Comment: I found the problem :). It was caused by `\backmatter` which I had put in front of `appendix`, instead of after it.

Comment: @Matthias Nice to hear this :) Also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/numbering-of-appendices-in-the-backmatter-of-a-book. Especially Caramdir's answer.