# \appendix chapter number not display

Tags: chapters, appendices

I am using following commands for Appendix:

```
\appendix 
\chapter{First Appendix} 
\input{AppendixA}
```

and it display chapter but without chapter number.

```
Frist Appendix  (no appendex number A)
.1 section title
.1.1 subsection title
```

I browsed this forum and found some tips but they could not solve my problem. if i use these commands:

```
\appendix \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}

\chapter{First Appendix} 
\input{AppendixA}
\chapter{Second Appendix} 
\input{AppendixB}
```

then out put is:

```
Frist Appendix   0 (appendex number starts from 0 not A)
A.1 section title
A.1.1 subsection title

Frist Appendix  0 (it repeat same number with all chapters)
A.1 section title
A.1.1 subsection title
```

Customized class file can be found [here](https://github.com/CourtneyChancellor/gsd2012/blob/master/these-LUNAM.cls).

May be it is due to conflict with other packages, i am using following packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, squeezeCommittee, fancyChapter, fancyPart]{these-LUNAM}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{paralist} % %for inline  numbering
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% to resize tables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

% to draw graphics in latex
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes, arrows}
\tikzset{
    events/.style={ellipse, draw, align=center},
}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\geometry{inner=4.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{times}
\RequirePackage[bookmarks,%
                colorlinks,%
                urlcolor=blue,%
                citecolor=blue,%
                linkcolor=blue,%
                hyperfigures,%
                pagebackref,%
                pdfcreator=LaTeX,%
                breaklinks=true,%
                pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,%
                bookmarksopen=true,%
                bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

% to set 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{minitoc}
```

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}`

Comment: What class are you actually using?

Comment: Thanks @karlkoeller, I used `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\Alph{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}` for all chapters so it works.

Comment: It should work with `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}` `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}`. Probably the last one is not even needed.

Comment: Is your class file available somewhere in the web?

Comment: https://github.com/CourtneyChancellor/gsd2012/blob/master/these-LUNAM.cls

Comment: I've tried adding an `\appendix` in the `main.tex` which comes with your class file and it works fine without adjustments...

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to put an appendix in the `\frontmatter`?

Comment: I'm suspecting you have a `\backmatter` command before `\appendix`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, there is a \backmatter command before \appendix

Comment: @user986789 After a `\backmatter` command, numbering of chapters is disabled. Remove it; you won't need any redefinition of `\thechapter` or `\thesection`.

Comment: Thank you all of you, problem is identified as in bad placement of `\backmatter` command. Now every thing is ok.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the end, your numbering problem of appendices is due to a bad placement of `\backmatter` which appears too early : all numbering is suppressed after it.
Look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/numbering-of-appendices-in-the-backmatter-of-a-book)

The proper ordering for a thesis would be :

```
\chapter{Perspectives ....}
<some input>
\appendix
\chapter{Comparison table for ....}
<some input>
\chapter{Implementation ....}
<some input>
%------------
\backmatter
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms
\tableofcontents
%-------------
\bibliographystyle{mybibstylewithoutbst}
\bibliography{mybibfileswithoutbib}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was the problem of `\backmatter` command. It was not at proper place. I am really thankful for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2):

Doe's it mean that you explicitly involve de A, and B in your definition ?

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{B\Alph{chapter}}
```

It's up to you to do that, but this breaks `LaTeX` logic, and will likely give strange results in the TOC.

I standard classes `report` and `book`, as  in Koma-script `scrbook`, as in `memoir`,
the `\appendix` command perform the change from the name chapter to appendix and at the same time switch to Alph numbering , starting from A (counter is set to 1).

EDIT : OK I have loaded your class. It is based on the standard `book` class.
It is rather buggy because it loads packages in random order, and also assume that some others have bean loaded by user, the option set is strange looking, and to switch it to english you need to not use the `english` option !(after all I'm French too !)

Any way, it compiles and with the code (using the *assumed* packages)

```
\documentclass[11pt,fancyPart]{these-LUNAM}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{The first chapter}
Un petit chapeau pour mon chapitre
\section{a normal section}
\lipsum[1]
\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}
\section{An appendix section}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

I can not reproduce your problem  as shown here :

[image]

My guess is that you use other packages that break the class...

Comment: Thanks, Yes i found its web link https://github.com/CourtneyChancellor/gsd2012/blob/master/these-LUNAM.cls

Comment: I am using the same class in the same way. But it do not prind the Appendix numbering as described in the question. May be there is a conflict of \appendix package with other packages?

Comment: please check i updated my post by the list of used packages.

Comment: I'm surprised that it ever works. For example `babel` is required to make the class working, tough it isn't  loaded neither by it nor by you... and same thing for `geometry` !
Have you tried to downgrade this complex sequence of packages? 
 
Even with this preamble i can't reproduce the problem....

Comment: When i use `\usepackage[english, french]{babel}` then it gives an error clash for package babel. I want to downgrade but when i need these packages.

Comment: It seems that the class you are using is (more or less) different with the one at the provided URL. When adding `babel` as you said, I have no option clash (because the corresponding `\RequirePackage` ins commented out in the class. In contrast, I get a lot of `geometry` errors because it is used i the class but not loaded !!

Comment: Thanks again, you can download my original class file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xrgfudlcljkpxw/these-LUNAM.cls). Now i used `\usepackage[babel]` at the end of the list of packages, so there is no error but appendix remains.

Comment: The class is actually very different. Especially because it actually loads `babel`, `geometry`, and many others. But I still can reproduce your problem !

Comment: Please notice that `minitoc` and `breakurl` claim to have modified the definition of `\chapter`. May be have you in your `input`-ed files some offending command which make the trickery  dieing (`\chapter` is  actually modified by the class, `appendix`, `babel`, `hyperref`, `fancychapter`, `minitoc`, etc.) Hence the surprising thing is that it still more ore less works...

Comment: I dont think there are any offending commands in inputed files. I use following commands `\chapter{Introduction}\label{Chapter1}
\input{chapter_1}` and in the chapter file `\singlespacing
\minitoc
\label{chap6_Exp}
\newpage
\doublespacing`. Rest of the chapter has just section and subsection commands.

Comment: You can find master .tex file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50di5wn3yx2i8pd/these.tex)