# Problem with Chapters in appendix mode not having a label

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, appendices, labels

I have a main file where I include several chapters including a couple of appendices, like this:

```
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
...

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
...
\include{chapter7}

\backmatter

\include{appendixA}
\include{appendixB}
```

Inside the `appendixA.tex`, I have:

```
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A: my Title}
\label{app:A}
```

When I reference `\ref{app:A}` I get the label

```
7.3.3
```

which is the label of the last subsection of the chapter before the Appendix A
also, tables in the main sections appear as

```
Table 1
```

instead of:

```
Table A.1
```

It looks like the top level (chapter) numbering doesn't start at all, since the label refers to the last subsection.
How do I make the appendix have a lable of its own?

Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to the group.  does this question help?  [Numbering of appendices in the backmatter of a book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1884/579)

Comment: yes it does! How could I have been so blind. Thanks a lot!