# Placing the appendices after the backmatter in a thesis

Tags: chapters, appendices

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/numbering-of-appendices-in-the-backmatter-of-a-book) question points out that in the book class, as soon as the `\backmatter` command appears, the chapter numbering ceases to work properly. Thus, one is essentially forced to put the bibliography after the appendices.  In principle, I agree with this ordering. However, my university's administration requires that the contents of my thesis appear in the following order:

- Intro and so forth
- Body
- Bibliography
- Appendices

It is causing me a major headache to get the numbering of the appendix chapters to appear at all. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: What does "ceasing to work properly" mean? One could circumvent some of the implications of `\backmatter`.

Comment: @Michael Mods can't merge accounts: you'll need to use the help link (bottom of the page) to ask the StackExchange staff to sort it out.

Comment: Just don't issue `\backmatter`; by default the bibliography is not numbered.

Comment: @Joesph Wright: Thanks for the advice. Why, don't we delete these comments?  I've deleted my first one.

Answer (score 8):

Simplest hack is to use a group like

```
{             %%<--- start the group
  \backmatter
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \bibliography{xampl}
  }             %%<--- end the group
  \appendix
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \chapter{Some front matter}
  \mainmatter
  \chapter{some main matter}
  \nocite{*}
  {             %%<--- start the group
  \backmatter
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
  \bibliography{xampl}
  }             %%<--- end the group
  \appendix
  \chapter{appendix}
  \section{some section in appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]